# Break out from JavaScript variable

Tags: javascript, syntax

So, I have the following code:

```
<script type="text/javascript">

var name = prompt("What's your name?");
var greeting = "Hello " + name + " :D";

console.log(greeting);
</script>
```

I am trying to break out from name variable. For example: answering the question by

```
"alert(1);\\
```

In browser console, printing name variable shows the following:

[image: name content]

Now, when trying to create a second variable with the same content it produces an error.

[image: test variable]
Why does "name" contain invalid syntax content? and is there any way to break out from the variable in this scenario?

Comment: Cause you have to escape the second ", otherwise it is treated as the end of the string literal.

Comment: either that or use single quotes to enclose the string

Answer (score 1):

When you input `"alert(1);\\` in the prompt, the special characters are automatically escaped and the input is assigned to `name`, but when you are doing that via the console or a script, you have to escape the characters manually. Since you wrote the string using double-quotes, the correct way to do the assignment would be:

```
var test = "\"alert(1);\\\\";
```

When uing single-quotes, you wouldn't have to escape the double-quotes:

```
var test = '"alert(1);\\\\';
```

What I did here is escape the required characters by putting a `\` before them. What you see when you try to view the value of `name` is the actual content without the escaping.

Answer (score 0):

JavaScript believes that you are ending the string literal at the second quotation mark.

Two possible solutions:

1. Wrap with single quotes: `test = '"alert(1)\\'`
2. Escape the second quote: `test = "\"alert//"`